# Why we can do : Base *base = new Derived; while we can not do Derived *derived = new Base?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Now let's say the base class contains some functions and the derived class obviously inherits from the base class...
so the derived class containes functions from the base class plus additional few functions of its own. hence we shouldn't be able to do `Base *base = new Derived;` because derived has more functions than base so a base pointer to a derived member shouldn't be possible because it won't be able to call those additional derived functions. on the other hand `Derived *derived = new Base` should be alowed because a derived pointer can containe all the functions from base without any data loss right ?
then again Why we can do : Base *base = new Derived;  while we can not do  Derived *derived = new Base ?

Comment: Because a `Base` object is not a `Derived` object? It doesn't have any of the functions or variables that a `Derived` object should have

Comment: *"a bass pointer to a derived member shouldn't be possible because it won't be able to call those additional derived functions"* - I fail to see the problem. Why does it matter that you cannot access some functions that could *possibly*  be there?

Comment: `Base *bass = new Derived` is valid, because a `Derived` is a `Base`.   `Derived *derived = new Base` is not valid because a `Base` is not a `Derived`.    The "is-a" relationship between categories of object (aka classes) only goes one direction - for example, "a dog is a mammal" is always a true statement, but "a mammal is a dog" is not always true.   There is no type of object in which "A is-a B" and "B is-a A" are both true, unless A and B are identical categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesper already answered the question well but I thought I could provide context by responding to your specific example

```
Derived *derived = new Base
```

and then you say "this should be alowed because a derived pointer can containe all the functions from base without any data loss right ?"

it's true that if you called `derived->SomeBaseMethod()` things could work (in theory), but what should happen if you tried to call some method that only existed on `Derived`? `derived->SomeDerivedMethod()`. Since the actual type pointed to is a `Base` object there would be no derived method to execute.

now if you had `Base* b = new Derived` then the compiler would only allow you to call `base` methods on `b` (which would be defined for all `Derived` objects) but would not allow you to call any derived methods since the type of `b` is `base`. Hence this would be safe whereas `Derived* d = new Base` would not

Answer (score 2):

Any `Derived` *is* a `Base`, but a `Base` is not a `Derived`.

If you have a base class like `Animal` it's fine to have a pointer to such initialized by a derived class `Human` - a human can do all the animal things. It *is* an animal.

But you cannot initialize a pointer to a Human with just an animal since when we then try to use it as a human it would be missing all the human bits since it was only created as a base animal.

Comment: well that's what I'm saying. a Derived is a Base, but a Base is not a Derived so I can do Derived *derived = new Base

Comment: @VoIdProduction Since a `Base` is not a `derived`, why would you expect to be able to have a `Derived *` that points to a `Base` instance? It would be missing all the `Derived` parts, making it *not* a valid `Derived *`.

Comment: @v A Ferrari is a Car. But a Car is not necessarily a Ferrari. If the Car is actually a Yugo, driving it like a Ferrari will end in fine comedy or a disaster, depending on the driver.